# What are the verb properties of sentences of this type?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, active-voice

"Click on the *Open File* button."

This is a common type of sentence that's communicated in technical documentation. I'm trying to understand the five properties of the verb used in sentences of these types. Please help me improve my understanding, if necessary.

- **Voice**: Since the omitted subject, namely, "You" is acting, the voice of the verb is active.
- **Mood**: Since the subject is omitted from the sentence, the mood of the verb is imperative. Moreover, the documentation is providing instruction (or orders) to the reader.
- **Tense**: The verb is written in the present tense.
- **Person**: Since the documentation is addressing the user of the software, this sentence is in the second person: "You click on the *Open File* button.
- **Number**: The verb is agreeing with the number of a singular noun, namely, "You".

Comment: It would be much easier with examples of each. Why should one have to figure out the puzzle here? It really should say: Active versus passive voice. The way it is explained is meaningless to me. Since the omitted subject,, "you",  is acting??

Comment: The action is punctive rather than durative, and one assumes semelfactive rather than iterative. Arguably, 'click on' is unary/transitive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you think all that jargon is helpful?

Comment: It's an English imperative. Therefore it is unspecified for tense or number.

Comment: Thank you, @EdwinAshworth, for introducing new ways in which I can categorize verbs. Indeed as Labmie regards them, they're jargon, but only at first. Importantly they're points of departure for further learning.

Comment: I think you're over-analyzing it.  It's an imperative.  Imperatives don't have a subject or a tense or a number.

Comment: @Lambie My understanding of the question is that OP has picked up that there are 5 major categories covering the ways in which verbs are analysed, perhaps from a statement in a textbook starting 'There are 5 ways in which ...'. 'the five properties of the verb' seems a defining (there are 5) usage. I'm pointing out that this would not be a comprehensive list.

Comment: My sincerest apologies. I didn't realize the question was **only about** "Click on the Open File button." **Obviously, an imperative**. (And that writing is an *absolute mess*.)

Comment: @stangdon, though imperatives have no grammatical subject, they do have the implied subject "you".

Comment: @parergon True, true.  I'm just saying that trying to analyze it in terms of "oh, this is second person singular" is maybe not that useful because it's not how any native speaker thinks of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice: You are correct - it is written in active voice.

Mood: Also correct - commands are the *imperative* mood.

Tense: Although "click" is the present participle of the verb, imperative statements use the *infinitive* form of verbs, but omitting the 'to'. An imperative statement can't really be said to be in the 'present' tense, because the action isn't carried out until the person receiving the command puts it into action.

Person: You are correct - it is the second person, because it is addressing the reader directly. Although the pronoun 'you' isn't used in the sentence, it is tacit whoever is reading it is the intended audience.

Number: "You" isn't only a singular pronoun. A teacher would address an entire class as "you". And you cannot assume that this instruction will only read by one person - what if a teacher read the book aloud to a class? But this seems irrelevant anyway, because the verb would not change - you click, we click, they click... there is no different form for plurals.

Comment: Thanks, @Astralbee. You've given me the confirmations and clarifications for which I was seeking.